# C - can not convert 1 argument from int to int[][4]

Tags: c, arrays, function

I have an error with C compiler and I can't do any thing , I surf the web for a solution but failed to solve the problem

**First error:**`error C2664: 'int get_min_distance(int *[][4],int,int,int,int)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'int *[][4]'`

Second error:`IntelliSense: argument of type "int" is incompatible with parameter of type "int (*)[4]"`

both error are in one line

**Code:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define inf  100000
int get_min_distance(int a[4][4], int b, int c, int d, int e);



int main(){
    int ras = 0;
    scanf("%d", &ras);

    int yal = 0;
    scanf("%d", &yal);

    int mabda = 0;
    scanf("%d", &mabda);

    int magsad = 0;
    scanf("%d", &magsad);


    int gf[4][4];
    gf[0][0] = 0;
    gf[0][1] = 1;
    gf[0][2] = inf;
    gf[0][3] = 1;
    gf[0][4] = 5;
    gf[1][0] = 9;
    gf[1][1] = 0;
    gf[1][2] = 3;
    gf[1][3] = 2;
    gf[1][4] = inf;
    gf[2][0] = inf;
    gf[2][1] = inf;
    gf[2][2] = 0;
    gf[2][3] = 4;
    gf[2][4] = inf;
    gf[3][0] = inf;
    gf[3][1] = inf;
    gf[3][2] = 2;
    gf[3][3] = 0;
    gf[3][4] = 3;
    gf[4][0] = 3;
    gf[4][1] = inf;
    gf[4][2] = inf;
    gf[4][3] = inf;
    gf[4][4] = 0;



    int distance = get_min_distance(gf [4][4], ras, yal, mabda, magsad);     //Error is here on "gf [4][4]"
    printf("%d", distance);


}


int get_min_distance(int gf[4][4], int ras, int yal, int mabda, int magsad){

    int min = inf;
    int i = ras;
    int A[5];

    if (mabda == magsad){
        return 0;
    }
    if (yal >= ras - 1){
        return inf;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < ras; i++){
        if (gf[i][magsad] != 0 && gf[i][magsad] != inf){
            A[i] = gf[i][magsad] + get_min_distance(gf, ras, yal + 1, mabda, i);
            if (min>A[i] && A[i] > 0){
                min = A[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

error occur when we call `get_min_distance` function 
Any idea?
thanks

Comment: just pass `get_min_distance(gf, ras, yal, mabda, magsad)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supply the name of the array as the argument

```
int distance = get_min_distance(gf, ras, yal, mabda, magsad);     
                               ^^^
```

Also this initialization of the array is invalid

```
int gf[4][4];
gf[0][0] = 0;
gf[0][1] = 1;
gf[0][2] = inf;
gf[0][3] = 1;
gf[0][4] = 5;
     ^^^
gf[1][0] = 9;
gf[1][1] = 0;
gf[1][2] = 3;
gf[1][3] = 2;
gf[1][4] = inf;
     ^^^
gf[2][0] = inf;
gf[2][1] = inf;
gf[2][2] = 0;
gf[2][3] = 4;
gf[2][4] = inf;
     ^^^
gf[3][0] = inf;
gf[3][1] = inf;
gf[3][2] = 2;
gf[3][3] = 0;
gf[3][4] = 3;
     ^^^
gf[4][0] = 3;
  ^^^
gf[4][1] = inf;
  ^^^
gf[4][2] = inf;
  ^^^
gf[4][3] = inf;
  ^^^
gf[4][4] = 0;
  ^^^^^^
```

because the valid range of indices is `[0, 3]`

Answer (score 1):

`gf[4][4]` is an integer (out of bounds) of your `gf` array

Just pass the `gf` variable:

```
get_min_distance(gf, ras, yal, mabda, magsad)
```

note: this is wrong, out of bounds too, your array is undersized. `[4][4]` means that max legal index is `3`, else you're overwriting some memory you don't own:

```
gf[4][0] = 3;
gf[4][1] = inf;
gf[4][2] = inf;
gf[4][3] = inf;
gf[4][4] = 0;
```

(you probably mean `[5][5]` in your dimensionning)